# Get the value of an Ember Component in the controller

Tags: ember.js

Lets say I have a custom component called X.

```
<X>my value</X>
```

I now want to access the "my value" in the controller of X. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

A component does not have access to that content.

The `<X>` component is used in block form in your example. A component, which supports the block form, yields the execution context back to the caller. It does so at a place marked with `{{yield}}` keyword in its template. At that point the execution is yielded back to the caller. The component does not have any access to the code, which is run in that slot.

This is similar to the concept of a callback:

- You can detect if the caller is using block form by using `{{has-block}}` helper. This is similar as you can detect in a function if a callback is provided.
- You can pass context to the yielded block using positional params on the `{{yield}} keyword. This is similar to executing a callback passed in with arguments.
- You can render DOM before and after the yield slot by having silbings in the template. This is similar to executing code before and after the callback is executed.
- You can wrap the yield block in DOM. This is similar to passing the callback to another function, which is executed.
- But you can not inspect or mutate what is set by the caller as content for the block.

The feature helps to separate concerns and establish clear boundaries between components. If you face it as a limitation it's very likely that the boundaries between the different components in your application is not clear enough.